# How to apply changes to GUI of a WPF form when ViewModel is updated from a form other than one it was created on?

Tags: wpf, viewmodel

I have two forms:
`Form1` and `Form2`.
In `Form1 .ctor, I am setting the`DataContext` as under:-

```
 public ViewModel1 VM1;
 Public Form1()
 {
    InitializeComponent();
    VM1=Populate_View_Model();//This method populates the ViewModel
    this.DataContext = VM1;
 }
```

I have an event on this form that takes this ViewModel to another WPF form

```
 private void cmdButtonTemplate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     ViewModel1 VM1_Clone = GetCloneObject(VM1_Clone);  //Create a clone of ViewModel.Needed on Form2
     new Form2(this, VM1,VM1_Clone);
 }
```

Form2 is taking the current(this) instance of Form1 and its current ViewModel and a Clone of ViewModel as under:-

```
 ViewModel1 VM, VM_Clone;
 Form1 Objfrm1;
 public Form2(Form1 ObjectForm1, ViewModel1 OvjVM1, ViewModel1 ObjVM1_Clone)
 {
     Frm1 = ObjectForm1;
     VM = OvjVM1;
     VM_Clone = ObjVM1_Clone;
     Objfrm1 = ObjectForm1;
     this.DataContext = VM_Clone;
 }
```

Now,Form2 is making changes to VM1_Clone.
Once i have made those changes to VM_Clone,I have an event in Form2 where I am setting the VM_Clone to VM1 as under:-

```
   Form1 Frm1;
   private void cmdSave_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   {
      VM = VM_Clone;
   }
```

Now i wanted to refresh the GUI on Form1 with the updated ViewModel from Form2,ie VM.But the GUI on Form1 is not getting refreshed with new values of updated View Model.

I even tried setting the object instance of Form1(passed in the constructor of Form2) with the DataContext of Form1 from Form2 as under:-

```
   private void cmdSave_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   {
       //VM1 = VM1_Clone;
       Objfrm1.DataContext = VM1;
   }
```

This too did not yield any results.Plz tell how to apply the changes made to the ViewModel of a Form when the VieModel is changed from a Form other than on which it is created.

Comment: You should provide more general infos, about what you want to archive with that. I looks a bit, like you want to make a edit => save/cancel logic. For that, there are probably better ways.

Comment: I have a ViewModel created on  Form1 and it needs to be updated from  Form2.The ViewModel is getting updated in Form2,but the changes made to ViewModel in Form2 are not reflecting in the GUI of Form1.There are more than one ways of doing things always,but i want answer to how it is supposed to be done in this case?

Answer (score 0):

For me, it really looks like dirty code, and I can't provide a more elegant solution without more Infos. You should take a look at the Mvvm pattern.

> I have a ViewModel created on Form1 and it needs to be updated from Form2.The ViewModel is getting updated in Form2,but the changes made to ViewModel in Form2 are not reflecting in the GUI of Form1.There are more than one ways of doing things always,but i want answer to how it is supposed to be done in this case?

Set the datacontext of form1 to vm_clone. So instead of `VM=VM_Clone`, or `Objfrm1.DataContext=VM1` do

```
private void cmdSave_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Objfrm1.DataContext=VM_Clone;
}
```

Or just don't clone your viewModel if not necessary and instead give the same viewmodel instance to your Form2 as the datacontext.

Comment: There is a cancel button on the second form so tthat the user can return to form1 without effecting the changes of form2 if clicked.If i do what you say,then the changes get reflected on both the forms as and when there is a change on form2,which i don't want since there is cancel button on form2 as well.

Comment: Then just override the datacontext in the save method. Then in the cancel method you can close the form2 without doing anything. But keep in mind, that your original viewmodel istance is still unchanged! So if you want to work with this viewmodel from some instance variables, you have to switch them too, or pull the datacontext of form1 out into that variables.